# when you should handle error in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When to skip error handling? I don't think this make sense

```
exports function getItems(req, res, next) => {
    Item.find({}, function(err, items){
      if(err) throw Error()

      res.json(items)
    })
}
```

Because get will not fail most of the time. I'm sick of writing error handling in node. Now I skip GET request, just do handling for POST, PUT or DELETE.

I'm using async await, I have to do try catch in every GET, that's annoying.

```
router.get('/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await getUserFromDb({ id: req.params.id })
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e) 
  }
})
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: This article should be the one you are looking for https://odino.org/async-slash-await-in-expressjs/

Comment: @Héctor I felt it's redundant.

Comment: @ShyamBabu thanks for that, that's exactly I wanted.